# Flat UI Checkbox style not applying on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I am using the Flat UI from http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

I copied all the files over and the code from the example page for checkbox.

However I noticed the checkbox doesn't appear as the styled checkbox but after I click the init button to manually apply the js then will it appears as the styled checkbox.

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Daily Tracker Settings</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../dist/css/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="../dist/css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" role="form">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mbl">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4>Plugin methods</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox100">
                                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="radio" value="" id="checkbox100" required>
                                Checkbox

                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-check="#checkbox100">Check</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-uncheck="#checkbox100">Uncheck</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-toggle="#checkbox100">Toggle</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-indeterminate="#checkbox100">Indeterminate</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-determinate="#checkbox100">Determinate</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-disable="#checkbox100">Disable</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-enable="#checkbox100">Enable</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-destroy="#checkbox100">Destroy</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-radiocheck-init="#checkbox100">Init</button><br>
                        <br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

        </div>


        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="../dist/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="../dist/js/vendor/video.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $('button:not([type="submit"])').on('click', function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);

                if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-check')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-check');
                    $(el).radiocheck('check');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-uncheck')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-uncheck');
                    $(el).radiocheck('uncheck');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-toggle')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-toggle');
                    $(el).radiocheck('toggle');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-indeterminate')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-indeterminate');
                    $(el).radiocheck('indeterminate');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-determinate')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-determinate');
                    $(el).radiocheck('determinate');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-disable')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-disable');
                    $(el).radiocheck('disable');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-enable')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-enable');
                    $(el).radiocheck('enable');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-destroy')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-destroy');
                    $(el).radiocheck('destroy');
                } else if (!!$this.attr('data-radiocheck-init')) {
                    var el = $this.attr('data-radiocheck-init');
                    $(el).radiocheck();
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: The demo page has `class="custom-checkbox"` on the checkboxes. Did you try that?

Comment: tried using different classes from all their example, but their documentation page for the implementation uses just checkbox. And the style will apply after i manually apply it using the button click method in their example: $(el).radiocheck();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually initializing all checkboxes with the style creates the checkbox properly. Not sure why in the source's examples they didn't have to do this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(':checkbox').radiocheck();
    });
</script>
```